# Azure App service with App service plan using ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We have created Azure app service with App service plan using ARM templates. However i have below questions regarding the same.

1. What is the difference between **workerSize** and **workerSizeId**
2. Using ARM template we have created app service with properties **workerSizeId** and **numberOfWorkers**. In Template we haven't provided **workerSize** , will **workerSizeId** in consideration for that app service.
3. Is there any possibility to see in which **WorkerPool** (ex: workerSize,workerSizeId) app service is hosted

ARM Template :

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
  "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
    "workerSizeId": "3",
    "numberOfWorkers": "4",
    "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('hostingEnvironment')]"
  },
  "sku": {
    "Tier": "PremiumV2",
    "Name": "P3v2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between workerSize and workerSizeId

`workerSize` - VM size of the worker pool instances.

`workerSizeId` - Worker size ID for referencing the worker pool.

> In Template we haven't provided workerSize , will workerSizeId in consideration for that app service.

As you create webapp with new app service plan, the `workerSize` also include in it.

[image]

> Is there any possibility to see in which WorkerPool (ex: workerSize,workerSizeId) app service is hosted

If you are using [ASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-app-service-environment-intro), **each worker pool contains compute resources allocated to App Service Plans**, which in turn contain one or more Azure App Service apps. Since there can be up to three different worker pools in an App Service Environment, you have the flexibility to choose different compute resources for each worker pool.

Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2019-08-01/hostingenvironments) to set workerpool.